# Html Agility Pack Loop Through Table - Get cell value based on previous cell value

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, phantomjs, html-agility-pack

I have multiple tables and Location Value is given in different index order.
How can I get location value if previous cell string is "Location" when I loop through table. On below example it is cells[7] but on other table it will be 9. How can I conditionally get values after cells inner text is "Location"? Basically find the cell "Location" get inner text of next cell.

Html Table:

```
<table class="tbfix FieldsTable"">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="name">Last Movement</td>
        <td class="value">Port Exit</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="name">Date</td>
        <td class="value">26/06/2017 00:00:00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="name">From</td>
        <td class="value">HAMBURGE</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="name">Location</td>
        <td class="value">EUROGATE  HAMBURG</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="name">E/F</td>
        <td class="value">E</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Controller Loop Through:

```
foreach (var eachNode in driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//table[contains(descendant::*, 'Last Movement')]")))
                {
                    var cells = eachNode.FindElements(By.XPath(".//td"));
                    cd = new Detail();

                    for (int i = 0; i < cells.Count(); i++)
                    {
                        cd.ActionType = cells[1].Text.Trim();
                        string s = cells[3].Text.Trim();
                        DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(s);
                        if (_minDate > dt) _minDate = dt;
                        cd.ActionDate = dt;

                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your foreach loop you could use this:

```
var location = eachNode.FindElement(By.XPath(".//td[contains(text(),'Location')]/following-sibling::td));
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data is always structured like that I would loop over all the  tags and add the data to a dictionary.

Try something like this:

```
Dictionary<string,string> tableData = new Dictionary<string, string>();
var trNodes = eachNode.FindElements(By.TagName("tr"));

foreach (var trNode in trNodes)
{
    var name = trNode.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".name")).Text.Trim();
    var value = trNode.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".value")).Text.Trim();

    tableData.Add(name,value);
}

var location = tableData["location"];
```

You would have to add validation and checks for the dictionary and the structure but that is the general idea.